# Prevent jboss application server from getting picked up by load balancer?

Tags: jboss, load-balancing, mod-cluster

There are two mod cluster load balancers running in my network and I want to exclude one from picking up my jboss application server nodes.

I want the nodes to be served exclusively by one of the balancers. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the multicast `ip:port` in the load balancer and jboss application servers.

The multicast was set to default for all instances and thus why both load balancers were picking up my nodes. By setting the multicast address to a specific `ip:port` combination in one of the load balancers and the application servers, I was able to restrict application servers to the one load balancer.